# how to remove matched tags but leave content with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, replace

I have HTML like this:

```
<div>
 <div class="a">
  content1
 </div>
 content 2
 <div class="a">
  <b>content 3</b>
 </div>
</div>
```

and I want to get rid of the div's of class="a" but leave their content. My initial attempt was:

```
$("div.a").replaceWith($(this).html());
```

However *this* is undefined. How would you do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try

```
$("div.a").each(function(){
    $(this).replaceWith($(this).html());
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Replacing elements with their stringified HTML content will nuke any event handlers that might be in place.  This won't:

```
$("div.a").each(function () {
    $(this).replaceWith($(this.childNodes));
});
```

Comment: If you have same class nested many levels this answer works perfectly. Accepted answer doesn't. +1

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery you could also use [contents](https://api.jquery.com/contents/) and [unwrap](https://api.jquery.com/unwrap/).

```js
$(".parent").find(".a").contents().unwrap();
```

```html
<div class="parent">
 <div class="a">
  content1
 </div>
 content 2
 <div class="a">
  <b>content 3</b>
 </div>
</div>
```