# How to select HTML elements which don't have any attributes defined on them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to use jQuery to locate all DIV tags that have no attributes on them and apply a class to each. Here's a sample HTML:

```
<div id="sidebar">
  <div>Some text goes here</div>
  <div class="something">something goes here</div>
  <div>Another div with no attributes.</div>
</div>
```

So, I need to take that and turn it into this:

```
<div id="sidebar">
  <div class="myClass">Some text goes here</div>
  <div class="something">something goes here</div>
  <div class="myClass">Another div with no attributes.</div>
</div>
```

How do you locate elements of type `div` that have no attributes via jQuery? Thanks.

Comment: No attributes of any type or just no class attribute?

Comment: No attributes of _any_ kind, so a totally "naked" div: `<div>`.

Comment: Is there any other way to solve what you're doing without resorting to searching for "naked" divs?

Comment: The code is being generated by a SharePoint 2010 content query web part; any column value from a list with "Rich Text" has a "naked" DIV wrapped around it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here you go:

```
$('div', '#sidebar').filter(function () {
    return this.attributes.length === 0;
})
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/phbU9/

The [`attributes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.attributes) property returns a list of all attributes set on the element. "Naked" elements have an empty `attributes` list.

**Update:** Be sure to read [Tim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7010917/jquery-to-find-div-tags-without-any-attributes/7260172#7260172) below which provides a solution for older versions of IE, since my own solution doesn't work in IE8 and below.

Comment: Seems very flimsy, if there is any other kind of attribute this would no longer work. There are better ways of doing it using jQuery selectors (In my opinion, atleast).

Comment: Thanks, Šime. That works. How do you add a style that will force the DIV to not cause a line break?

Comment: @Alex Depends on the situation. If the element should be inline, use SPAN elements. Another option would be to float it.

Comment: @Henry But that's the intent: to select "naked" elements - elements that haven't got any kind of attributes. I don't know why the OP needs this, but his question is clear.

Comment: Thanks, @Šime. Can I remove the DIV and its matching closing tag that the above jQuery finds? This would fix the problem... why even have "naked" div tags?

Comment: @Alex You can remove those DIV's by appending `.remove()` to my code above - [see here](http://jsfiddle.net/phbU9/4/). However, even "naked" DIV's are useful if they have text-content inside them (obviously).

Comment: Well, actually, it would be a "replace()", not remove. So replace the tag with its contents; similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018050/how-to-remove-matched-tags-but-leave-content-with-jquery

Comment: @Alex Ah now I see... you just wanted to remove the tags, not the whole element. In that case, replacing the DIV element with its contents works.

Comment: This won't work in older IE (certainly 6 and 7, not sure about 8 or 9), where the attributes collection contains entries for all possible attributes, not just those specified in the HTML. Your own jsFiddle shows the problem.

Answer (score 2):

@Šime's answer is close but doesn't work in IE 6, 7 or 8, where an element's `attributes` collection has an entry for every possible attribute, not just those specified in the HTML. You can get round this by checking each attribute object's `specified` property.

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/timdown/6MqmK/1/

Code:

```
$("div").filter(function() {
    var attrs = this.attributes, attrCount = attrs.length;
    if (attrCount == 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < attrCount; ++i) {
            if (attrs[i].specified) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Good point. I can confirm that my solution works in IE9, but not in IE8.

Comment: Thanks, Tim. That's a more comprehensive solution. You guys are too good :)

Answer (score 0):

check this out:

http://jsfiddle.net/thilakar/CHux9/

Answer (score 0):

You need to give some sort of selector, in this case Ive used your side bar but it can be anything. Then get the children that have no class attribute and add a new class. See JSFiddle for the example:

http://jsfiddle.net/HenryGarle/q3x5W/

```
  $("#sidebar").children('div:not([class])').addClass('newClass');
```

So this would return the 2 elements with no class tag and leave the sidebar and div with the class completely unaffected.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of jQuery's [has attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/) and the [not selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/). For example:

```
$('div:not([class], [id])').addClass('myClass');
```

[jsFiddle demonstrating this](http://jsfiddle.net/Spycho/HTCr7/)

With this approach, you need to explicitly specify the attributes to check the presence of. Sime's solution would apply the class to divs that do not have any attributes at all.

Comment: Any reason for the down-vote? Perhaps I could modify the answer if I knew what people thought was wrong with it?

Comment: Same happened for my answer, it just happens. Most likely because our answers don't fit the exact question although they are a more sensible approach.

Answer (score 0):

To expound upon Tim Down's answer, I recommend checking that the attrs var not null special cases where the html has comment tags, etc.

Answer (score -1):

try $('div:not([class])').addClass('myClass');
it is a general approach because the class will apply to all the div that have no class

Comment: That would add 'myClass' to the #sidebar div as well, which is not what the OP wants.

Comment: i gave a general answer and he can custom it for his example

Comment: That's great, but it needs to be said that it isn't a complete solution so that the people don't just blindly copy it into their code and assume it does exactly what the question is asking for. I down-voted this answer because it doesn't do what the OP asked for. Perhaps if you edit the answer to say that it is a general approach that requires customisation, that would be better. I would say your answer is valuable as a partial solution, it just needs to say that.

Answer (score -6):

```
$('#sidebar div')` or more general `$('div'); //returns collections of divs
```

to answer the question:

```
$('#sidebar div').addClass('myClass');
```

Comment: Thanks, Phil. But are those DIVs without any attributes? In other words the DIVs that are simply `<div>something</div>`?

Comment: In this case `div.something` will become `div.something.myClass`

Comment: That doesn't do what the OP asked... That would apply the class 'myClass' to the div that already has a class of 'something'. Also, it doesn't locate div tags that have no attributes (which is what the OP wanted).