# Replace all instances particular tag when HTML may be malformed

Tags: jquery, asp-classic

We're trying to write a script which replaces deprecated tags, such as `<font>`, with their content. What we have is something along the lines of:

```
while($("font").length > 0) {
    $("font").each(function() {
        $(this).replaceWith($(this).html());
    });
}
```

The while loop is just because if a font tag is replaced with it's content and one of that elements children is also a font tag then it catches both parent and child.

Our problem is that we have no control over the content being output - this is entered by our clients. One example of malformed HTML which we've seen recently is `<p><font><span><font><div></font><strong></strong><strong></div></span></font></p>`. Obviously this is majorly malformed and in the ideal world our clients would enter it correctly. The above script works perfectly on this in all decent browsers - Chrome, Firefox & Safari - and surprisingly IE 9. However it breaks in IE 6-8, resulting in none of the content within these tags being displayed. What we're aiming for is that all font tags are replaced and content within them is still displayed.

Does anyone know of any way we can achieve the desired effect with either jQuery or classic ASP?

Also note that in this particular clients case it is pretty basic - only 1 tag has been requested to be replaced. Other cases include tags which are added by Word when they transfer the text from Word into the website, `<i>`, `<b>`, `<span>` and so on.

Thanks in advance,
Regards,
Richard

Comment: Is that malformed code generated by a WYSIWYG editor? If so it'd probably be an easier solution to use a better WYSIWYG which generates clean code.

Comment: You would do better with `$('font').replaceWith(function(){return $(this).contents();});`, rather than copying the HTML. That would get rid of the need for the `while` loop.

Comment: Yes - that's our thinking, however we're just the customisation team - updating the editor is up to the core code guys but they won't touch it with a barge pole. They know it's rubbish but our product is no longer actively sold and upgrading this is too risky.

Comment: @lonesomeday, I have just tried your solution as well as that documented at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018050/how-to-remove-matched-tags-but-leave-content-with-jquery (using `this.childNodes`) but IE displays the same.

Comment: @ClarkeyBoy Yes, I'm afraid it won't solve the problem, but they are better solutions all the same.

Comment: I managed to resolve this in the end. It seems that even just `$("#myElem").html($("#myElem").html());` causes issues. However if I use `$("#myElem")[0].innerHTML = $("#myElem").html();`, it works fine. It's like jQuery does some processing when you set the HTML of an element, rather than simply setting the innerHTML like anyone would think it does.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be easier to replace all <font> and </font> tags from the output? This would in the given case still not deliver a validating XHTML code (<div> inside of a <span>, unclosed <strong>), but maybe it would suffice to view the text.

Here is how you could do this in classic ASP using regexp:

```
function removeFontTags(s_text)
    dim obj_regex
    set obj_regex = new RegExp

    obj_regex.IgnoreCase = true
    obj_regex.Global = true
    obj_regex.Pattern = "\<\/?font\>"

    removeFontTags = obj_regex.replace(s_text, "")

    set obj_regex = Nothing
end function

Response.Write removeFontTags("<p><font><span><font><div></font><strong></strong><strong></div></span></font></p>")

' returns: <p><span><div><strong></strong><strong></div></span></p>
```

But maybe you could add further sanitation this way to display what you need.

Comment: Thanks @gpinkas, that would work with tags which have no attributes certainly. I currently use jQuery to replace `<font ...>`, however I have found one flaw in this; what if they have, say, `<font title='bob > fred'>`? It will remove up to and including the `>` in the `title` attribute.. I can't see a way to accomplish this. I am going to try to remove all attributes from `font` tags instead; not ideal but it will have to do. I have also raised a case to try to get the tool which outputs this invalid HTML to the latest version (which evidently doesn't now).

Comment: Well, if you can be sure of the syntax for the attributes, you could easily enhance the regexp like so: `"\<\/?font(?:\s+\w+=\'[^']\')*\>"`. I think, replacing in ASP would be safer, to prevent problems with jQuery and invalid code structure...